# write output two dimensional array as Format-Table

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

My goal is to write a function that supports writing any array as a table, where the args given are the array, and the number of columns wanted in the table.

I have the following code...

```
Function PrintArrayAsTable
{
    Param ([String[]]$array ,[Int]$numOfItemsPerRow)

    $elementCounter = 1
    [String[]]$row = @()
    [String[]]$tableArray = @()

    ForEach ($element in $array)
    {
        $row += $element
        if ($elementCounter % $numOfItemsPerRow -eq 0)
        {
            $tableArray += ,($row)
            [String[]]$row = @()
        }
        $elementCounter++
    }

    if ($row)
    {
        $tableArray += ,($row)
        [String[]]$row = @()
    }

    $tableArray | Format-Table
}

[String[]]$array = @('SamAccountName', 'msRTCSIP-UserEnabled', 'msRTCSIP-OptionFlags', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer', 
                     'mail', 'msExchMasterAccountSid', 'homeMDB', 'proxyaddresses', 'legacyExchangeDN', 
                     'lastLogonTimestamp', 'logonCount', 'lastLogoff', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet', 'userAccountControl', 'whenCreated', 'whenChanged', 'accountExpires', 
                     'sn', 'givenName', 'displayName', 'distinguishedName', 'initials', 'l', 'st', 'street', 'title', 'description', 'postalCode', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'telephoneNumber', 'facsimileTelephoneNumber', 'info', 'memberOf', 'co', 'department', 'company', 'streetAddress', 'employeeNumber', 'employeeType', 'objectGUID', 'employeeID', 'homeDirectory', 'homeDrive', 'scriptPath', 'objectSid', 'userPrincipalName', 'url', 'msDS-SourceObjectDN', 'manager', 'extensionattribute8')

PrintArrayAsTable $array 5
```

This will print the following output...

```
SamAccountName msRTCSIP-UserEnabled msRTCSIP-OptionFlags msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer
mail msExchMasterAccountSid homeMDB proxyaddresses legacyExchangeDN
lastLogonTimestamp logonCount lastLogoff lastLogon pwdLastSet
userAccountControl whenCreated whenChanged accountExpires sn
givenName displayName distinguishedName initials l
st street title description postalCode
physicalDeliveryOfficeName telephoneNumber facsimileTelephoneNumber info memberOf
co department company streetAddress employeeNumber
employeeType objectGUID employeeID homeDirectory homeDrive
scriptPath objectSid userPrincipalName url msDS-SourceObjectDN
manager extensionattribute8
```

Instead, I want the format printout to be like the following...

```
SamAccountName             msRTCSIP-UserEnabled   msRTCSIP-OptionFlags     msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer
mail                       msExchMasterAccountSid homeMDB                  proxyaddresses              legacyExchangeDN
lastLogonTimestamp         logonCount             lastLogoff               lastLogon                   pwdLastSet
userAccountControl         whenCreated            whenChanged              accountExpires              sn
givenName                  displayName            distinguishedName        initials                    l
st                         street                 title                    description                 postalCode
physicalDeliveryOfficeName telephoneNumber        facsimileTelephoneNumber info                        memberOf
co                         department             company                  streetAddress               employeeNumber
employeeType               objectGUID             employeeID               homeDirectory               homeDrive
scriptPath                 objectSid              userPrincipalName        url                         msDS-SourceObjectDN
manager                    extensionattribute8
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to render the array in X equal-width columns, not arrange a 2-dimensional array into a table with named columns?

Comment: well the input arg is just an array. I separate it into a two dimensional array, so each array in the two dimensional array will be printed as a row of the table. The amount of columns will be based on the input arg of the function. In this example, we use `5`, so there will be 5 columns. The width should equal the longest string in that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Format-Wide`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849918.aspx) does basically what you describe already.

All you need to do is construct an object with a single property for each string, and then refer to that property name with `Format-Wide -Property`:

```
function Print-Grid
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Array,

        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [ValidateRange(1,24)]
        [int]$ColumnCount
    )
    $GridSplat = @{
        InputObject = $Array|ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{'Value' = $_}
        }
        Property    = 'Value'
    }

    if(-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ColumnCount'))
    {
        $GridSplat['AutoSize'] = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $GridSplat['Column'] = $ColumnCount
    }

    Format-Wide @GridSplat
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for the response. PowerGUI is showing a squiggly line under the V in '[Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,Position=0)]'. It says Parsing Error: The "=" operator is missing after a named argument. Any idea why this is? NOTE: the code does work with powershell.exe, but errors out when compiled with PowerGUI Script Editor version 1.9.5.966.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Because PowerGUI expects you to explicitly mark each named Parameter attribute either `$true` or `$false` (maybe for version 2.0 compliance, just a guess)

Comment: ah your right, after a little googling I found this... https://github.com/smurawski/PowerShellGuard/issues/4. All I did was remove lines `[Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,Position=0)]` and `[Parameter(Position=1)]`. Runs fine now for both Powershell and PowerGUI. Thanks :D

Comment: Don't remove them (they serve a purpose), just give them a value (ie. `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=0)]`)

Comment: Why construct objects when you can use calculated properties `$GridSplat = {InputObject = $Array; Property = {$_}; Force = $true}`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bit that is missing is getting your rows of data into neat, equal-width columns...

I'd try to work out the maximum width you'd need a column to be (say, the length of the longest string in the array plus 1). You could do this using:

```
$width = ($array | %{$_.Length} | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum + 1
```

And then you could pad out each element to this width:

```
$row += $element.PadRight($width)
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't _quite_ what you wanted, as **every** element is padded to the width of the longest one in the whole array. What you needed was each to be padded to the width of the widest, _per column_. Looks like @Mathias has a better answer!

Comment: Thanks, this is an option, but your right. However, it's good to know this method exists as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while trying to do something similar and seem to find a different way of doing this;

```
$arrayName | select-object -Property @{Name = 'Col1 name'; Expression = { $_[1]}},
                                     @{Name = 'Col2 name'; Expression = { $_[2]}},
                                     @{Name = 'Col3 name'; Expression = { $_[3]}},
                                     @{Name = 'Col4 name'; Expression = { $_[4]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to control the column format, here is the full answer;

```
$s1errorcode_list | select-object -Property @{Name = 'Col1 name'; Expression = { $_[1]}},
                                        @{Name = 'Col2 name'; Expression = { $_[2]}},
                                        @{Name = 'Col3 name'; Expression = { $_[3]}},
                                        @{Name = 'Col4 name'; Expression = { $_[4]}} | 
                       format-table -Property @{ Expression = 'Col1 name'; width=6 },
                                              @{ Expression = 'Col2 name'; width=84 },
                                              @{ Expression = 'Col3 name'; width=80 },
                                              @{ Expression = 'Col4 name'}
```